# Radio input checked

Tags: html, jquery, css, input, radio-button

I have 2 radio inputs. A,B

I an trying to make A as a selected radio by default.
And I want the following behavior: when A get hidden then B should get checked by default.

This is what I tried. Please take a look.

```
<div >
     <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="a" />
     <strong>A</strong>
</div>
<div>
     <input type="radio" checked=""  value="1" name="b" />
     <strong>
     B
    </strong>
</div>
<input type="text" onfocus="Javascript:document.forms[1].opt_payment[1].checked=true;" maxlength="20" value=" " name="" />
```

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by `a get hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `checked="checked"` for A. Also, if you want only one of A and B to be checked at a time, give them the same name but different values.

Comment: I did that.. I am also trying when both are visible and user click on B input type then the B's radio input should get selected Onfocus.

Answer (score 0):

`checked=""` means "Should be checked by default". There is no way to have the attribute present but indicate "not checked".

If you don't want a form control to be checked by default then **do not include any checked attribute for it**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div >
     <input id="radioA" type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="a" />
     <strong>A</strong>
</div>
<div>
     <input id="radioB" type="radio" value="1" name="b" />
     <strong>
     B
    </strong>
</div>
```

Script:

```
if($("#radioA").is(":hidden")){
       $("#radioB").attr("checked","checked");
}
```

you can also use

```
$("#radioB").attr("checked",true);
```

or use `prop` for jquery version > 1.6

```
$("#radioB").prop("checked",true);
```